# MySQL WHERE EXISTS evaluating to true for all records

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause, exists

I'm trying to run a query that retrives all records in a table that exists in a subquery.

However, it is returning all records insteal of just the ones that I am expecting.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x FROM T1 WHERE EXISTS 
      (SELECT * FROM T1 NATURAL JOIN T2 WHERE T2.y >= 3.0);
```

I've tried testing the subquery and it returns the correct number of records that meet my constraint.

But when I run the entire query it returns records that should not exists in the subquery.

Why is EXISTS evaluating true for all the records in T1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery, not a join in the subquery.  It is unclear what the right correlation clause is, but something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x
FROM T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.COL = T1.COL AND T2.y >= 3.0);
```

Your query has a regular subquery.  Whenever it returns at least one row, then the `exists` is true.  So, there must be at least one matching row.  This version "logically" runs the subquery for each row in the outer `T1`.

Comment: That work!! Thanks, I will accept this answer as soon as I can. I do have some confusion with correlated vs join. Why did mind behave like it was true all the time?

Comment: yours behaved as true all the time because the second query was fully independent and hence something did exist for every record in the table being evaluated. i.e. there was no way of aligning the subquery result to any specific row in T1, so all rows were returned.

Answer (score 2):

**Q: Why is EXISTS evaluating true for all the records in T1?**

**A:** Because the subquery returns a row, entirely independent of anything in the outer query.

The `EXISTS` predicate is simply checking whether the subquery is returning a row or not, and returning a boolean TRUE or FALSE.

You'd get the same result with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x FROM T1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1)
```

(The only difference would be if that subquery didn't return at least one row, then you'd get no rows returned in the outer query.)

There's no correlation between the rows returned by the subquery and the rows in the outer query.

---

I expect that there's another question you want to ask. And the answer to that really depends on what result set you are wanting to return.

If you are wanting to return rows from T1 that have some "matching" row in T2, you could use either a `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)`

Or, you could also use a join operation to return an equivalent result, for example:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT T1.x 
   FROM T1
NATURAL
   JOIN T2 
  WHERE T2.y >= 3.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes after seeing the example above I have a much better understanding of how EXISTS works. After adding the correlation between the outer and inner query I achived the correct results!

Comment: @JulioReyes: I'd give an example of the correlated subquery, but the `NATURAL JOIN` is effectively "hiding" the names of the columns that you are "matching" in `T1` and `T2`. My personal preference is to avoid using a `NATURAL JOIN`, because if it's "working" when T1 contains columns `(fa, fee, fi, fo, fum)` and T2 contains column `(doh, ray, me, fa)` ... adding another column to either T1 or T2, using name that matches the name of an existing column in the other table will "break" the query.  For example, adding column `me` to T1 would change what the NATURAL JOIN operation does.

Comment: Also, with the NATURAL JOIN, in order to "figure out" what columns are being "matched", the reader would need to compare the definitions of T1 and T2, to find all the columns that have the same name. (I prefer to write my queries so they won't "break" if someone adds a column to a table, and to not make it less necessary for the reader to consult the table definitions to find out which column names are being referenced.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. My query is no longer using natural join after I changed the subquery from a join to a correlation. I will definitely avoid using natural joins now that I see how they can break if they tables columns get added/changed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't working because there is no correlation between the outer query and the subquery being used. Below there is a correlation in the form of `and T1.id = T2.id`

```
SELECT DISTINCT x 
FROM T1 
WHERE EXISTS  ( SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.y >= 3.0 and T1.id = T2.id)
;
```

But, without knowing the data I'd hope you do NOT need to use "distinct" in that query, and this would produce the same result:

```
SELECT x 
FROM T1 
WHERE EXISTS  ( SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.y >= 3.0 and T1.id = T2.id)
;
```

An alternative, which probably would require distinct, is a variation ofh the second half of your second query

```
SELECT DISTINCT x FROM T1 NATURAL JOIN T2 WHERE T2.y >= 3.0
```

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense now! I wasn't doing any correlation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an INNER JOIN to get where you're trying to go:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.X
  FROM T1
  INNER JOIN T2
    ON T2.COL = T1.COL
  WHERE T2.Y > 3.0
```

Share and enjoy.